# Fourier: Does this function satisfy $c_n = ic_{-n}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the following fuction with T=2 and x defined for [-1,1]

$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      2(x+1) & -1 \leq x\leq -0.5 \\
      1 & -0.5 \leq x\leq 0.5 \\ 
      2(1-x) & 0.5 \leq x\leq 1 \\
   \end{cases}
$

Now I have this question:

Is it true that the coefficients of the exponential Fourier series of $f(x) $ satisfy $c_n = ic_{-n}$?

I'm not really sure how to prove this is true or false.

Comment: Why don't you just compute the $c_n$'s???

Comment: BTW, your function is odd. So, $c_n = -c_{-n}$.

Comment: @amsmath I know it's odd and that property can be applied so assume the statement is false? Because of the "i"

Comment: Because $f$ is odd, we have $a_k=0$ for all $k$. But $a_k = c_k+c_{-k}$.

Comment: @amsmath why is $f$ odd? to me it looks even

Comment: @Conrad Sure, you're right. So, $0 = b_k = i(c_k-c_{-k})$.

Comment: @Conrad it's true, sorry. $b_k$ is 0. Anyways the statement continues to be false I guess?

Comment: I think so - this is a cosine series so the opposite coefficients cannot be conjugate (unless the series is constant)

Comment: @Conrad thank you for your help